# Compare two associative arrays regarding the order of keys

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Suppose, we have 2 associative arrays:

```
<?php
$array1 = array(
    1 => 2,
    2 => 1,
);

$array2 = array(
    2 => 1,
    1 => 2,
);
```

They contain same elements, but in different order. I wanted to write a comparison function, that will give true only if:

1. Arrays have the same key => value pairs.
2. Order of pairs is the same.

So, I tried the following:

## 1 try

```
if ($array1 == $array2)
{
    print "equal\n";
}
```

Prints: equal

## 2 try

```
print count(array_diff_assoc($array1, $array1));
```

Prints: 0

## My custom function

Then I created the following function:

```
function compare(&$array1, &$array2)
{
    $n1 = count($array1);
    $n2 = count($array2);
    if ($n1 == $n2)
    {
        $keys1 = array_keys($array1);
        $keys2 = array_keys($array2);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $n1; ++$i)
        {
            if ($keys1[$i] == $keys2[$i])
            {
                if ($array1[$keys1[$i]] != $array2[$keys2[$i]])
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This works correctly, but it won't work, when we want this strict comparison applied for nested arrays of arrays because of `!=` operator in this if:

```
if ($array1[$keys1[$i]] != $array2[$keys2[$i]])
{
       return false;
}
```

This can be fixed, using a recursive function, switching by type of data. But this simplified version was ok for me.

Is there any standard solution for this type of comparison?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described under [array operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php), what you want is the `===` equality operator.

```
if ($array1 === $array2) {
    echo "same key pairs and same element order\n";
}
```

Comment: + for adding the doc link.

Comment: Note that `$array1 === $array2` doesn't do well with objects, even if they implement the magic `__toString` method, you'll always end up with false

Answer (score 0):

can you try the this below one. which returns true 
if the key=>value and will be in any order
otherwise returns false

```
$array1 = array(
1 => 2,
2 => 1);           
$array2 = array(
2 => 1,
1 => 2);

var_dump(compareArray($array1,$array2));

function compareArray ($array1, $array2)
{

foreach ($array1 as $key => $value)

{

if ($array2[$key] != $value)

 {


return false;
}

 }
return true;
 }
```