# PHP Easy way to compare two arrays: Same values, regardless of order

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Just a note of previous research on SO:

- search under "[php] array sort" (15,000 results)
- [compare two arrays where values are not in same order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273867) (does not cleanly address direct issue)
- [Compare two associative arrays regarding the order of keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17924178) (different issue)

At least I believe that:

Given the example:

```
$arr1 = [21, 23, 25];
$arr2 = [25, 21, 23];
```

It the easiest, nondestructive manner to compare these for equal values, regardless of order

```
$arr1s = $arr1;
$arr2s = $arr2;

sort($arr1s, SORT_NUMERIC);
sort($arr2s, SORT_NUMERIC);

$isSameValues = ($arr1s === $arr2s);
```

Or is there an easier, cleaner way to do this?

Comment: See the first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519847/comparing-arrays-in-php-without-caring-for-the-order

Comment: 1nflktd: Not sure if you meant the answer posited in the question of the first response. I need to streamline as best I can due to the hit that this is going to take. I have no option but to be making this call a metric $&%*tonne of times. :-/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `array_count_values`, which is `O(n)` vs `O(n log n)` for sorting

```
$a = [1, 1, 3, 2];
$b = [1, 2, 2, 3];
var_dump (array_count_values($b) == array_count_values($a)); //false
```

Note: this only works with arrays where all values are strings or ints.

Comment: Note that something like this `$a = [33];$b = [33, 3.3, 2.1];` would return true. Example: http://ideone.com/EytqqR

Comment: yes, but I really liked your answer, and I know that someone will see this in the future and will try to compare with floats and will complain about it, so I'm just informing already :p

Comment: @1nflktd fair enough, added a note to clarify the limitation :)

Comment: FuzzyTree: Are you saying that the array_count_values is O(n) and the double copy and sort being O(n long n)? If so, then I will try this as my lists are ALWAYS ints and should NEVER have duplicates. (Should being the operative term)

Comment: @LordAndrei each `array_count_values` is `O(n)` whereas each sort is `O(n log n)`, to be clear `array_count_values` handles duplicates correctly. my note about duplicates was regarding `array_diff`

Comment: @FuzzyTree At first I mistakingly left the === compare which failed. Going ack and checking the == worked very well. So, thank you for this suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You were very near to the right solution!
Here is your code fixed:

```
$arr1 = [21, 23, 25];
$arr2 = [25, 21, 23];

$arr1s = $arr1;
$arr2s = $arr2;

sort($arr1s, SORT_NUMERIC);
sort($arr2s, SORT_NUMERIC);

$isSameValues = ($arr1 == $arr2);
```

See it working here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b737d3a9cf45e077a0d1f2c0195f389b81ace4a3

If the two arrays have same keys and values, a `==` is enough, as shown [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php):

[image]